# How do I move my map markers in realtime on Qt?

Tags: qt, maps, mapbox, qtlocation, qtpositioning

I'm using Qt to run on Android. I'm working on a qtlocation map and I want to update my location in realtime. I have set my updateInterval: 1 (0.001 seconds) but MapQuickItem is still moving too late.

```
PositionSource {
    id: ps
    updateInterval: 500
    active: true
    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log(position.coordinate);
    }
}

Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent

    plugin: Plugin {
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter {
            name: "mapboxgl.mapping.items.insert_before"
            value: "road-label-small"
        }

        PluginParameter {
            name: "mapboxgl.access_token"
            value: "myToken"
        }

        PluginParameter {
            name: "mapboxgl.mapping.additional_style_urls"
            value: "Urls"
        }
    }

    MapQuickItem {
        zoomLevel: map.zoomLevel

        sourceItem: Image {
            id: carMarker
            source: "../images/circle.png"
        }

        coordinate: ps.position.coordinate
        anchorPoint.x: carMarker.width / 2
        anchorPoint.y: carMarker.height / 2
    }
}
```

Is there a way about that how can I move my marker in realtime?

and this the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxEWy.gif)

or this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLMuyWX4WQYw-L4jdx-sq-xstkjVRyCl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the update interval that you specify is usually interpreted as lower bound. But normally no position source will be giving you updates at that speed. Especially not smartphones GPS. Expect fastest updates to be around the 1 second